# How can I step directly into a function without stepping into intermediate functions for parameters?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, step-into

In Visual Studio 2013 (or any version really) and I am debugging a C++ project, I want to be able to bypass stepping into intermediate functions that are called due to parameters being passed into the function of interest.

How can I bypass stepping into these intermediate functions (not of interest directly) and just go straight to my function of interest?

For example, let's say I have a function that passes in a list of objects and another parameter that is a string. If I set a breakpoint and click the Step Into button or F8 then it is actually first steps into the functions necessary to get the list of objects ready as well as the string object. I don't care about these intermediate functions for the setup and I just want to go directly to my function of interest. Is there a setting to be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click -> Step Into Specific -> pick the function you want to step into.

Comment: If I have to do this every time and not be able to use F8 then it's actually more work. Is there a way to tell it to always step into specific?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could look into setting up a StepOver filter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx